# Bootstrap LESS takes 25s to be loaded in localhost

Tags: less

I did not have this problem 2 days ago, now it happens without me doing anything. I have my site.less file which includes bootstrap.less, and it takes 25s to load all the less files which is very annoying when developing

less: parsed http://localhost/css/dev/public.less successfully.

less: saving http://localhost/css/dev/public.less to cache.

less: css for http://localhost/css/dev/public.less generated in 26446ms

less: css generated in 26453ms

I was using Chrome and Firefox and both browsers have the same problem. I am not sure what is it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, to be clear, it looks like everything is local. but what isn't clear is what you're doing with the LESS and CSS. It's taking a while for the CSS to compile into LESS, but what are you using to compile? less.js?

So I'm assuming you're directly editing the LESS files and your goal is to have the LESS compile into CSS on the fly, and then you will use the CSS for production... right?

If my assumptions above were correct, don't use less.js during development the way you would if you were compiling LESS to CSS in the browser.

Use one of the solutions in this post: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25289/is-there-a-way-to-compile-less-files-to-css-so-that-every-browser-doesnt-have

Answer (score 0):

I figure out that I have changed the database (Redis) from localhost to a remote database. When I change it back to localhost, everything works as it is supposed to be. I am not sure how database connection can have anything to deal with less files.